# How to update GML layer without reloading local file?

Tags: openlayers-2, features, geojson, gml

I set up a GML layer with local GeoJSON file as data source:

```js
veclayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("vector", "localfile.json",
{
    format: OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.fixed()],
    styleMap: myStyleMap
});
```

Then later I change some of the attributes of GeoJSON data in the veclayer:

```js
veclayer.features[i].attributes.someAttr = value;
```

After all features are updated, I want to redraw the layer. I see some examples that uses the following method:

```js
function UpdateVecLayer(layer) {
        layer.loaded = false;
        layer.setVisibility(true);
        layer.refresh({force: true, params:{'key': Math.random()}});
    }
```

However, it doesn't work for me. I think it is because when I reload the layer, it just loads the local file again, and the attribute values are not changed. Can anyone tell me how to update the layer?

Comment: Are you modifying geometries? Do you really need to redraw the layer?

Comment: No, I don't modify geometries. I only modify attributes. And the layer is rendered according to the attribute. How can the layer show differently if not redrawn?

Answer (score 1):

Because GML layer is extended by Vector layer you can use strategies to save changes.
Probably this is possible to make it, but I never do it with local file.

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Save-js.html